# Finding midpoint between one observation and another in R

Tags: r

I have some data on bird parental care and I cannot work out how get the information I require from them.

I need to take the midway between the last observation with the parent (4) and the first observation when the parent was not with the family (3 = female care only, 2 = male care only), eg:

```
Date      Parent   Chick age
509        4             0
510        2             1
515        3             6
516        3             7
517        no chicks
```

So for the above set of data I would like to find:
Duration of male care 
Duration of female care

Can anyone help me understand how to go about doing this?
Thanks in advance for your help and please feel free to ask me to clarify things if the way I've worded this doesn't make sense, I'm very new to R!

Comment: How did you compute the values 7.5 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a single dataframe per chick and that there's only one care transition from family to male or female, the calculation would be done as follows:

`male_care_duration = min(chicks[chicks['parent']==2,]$datestamp, na.rm=TRUE) - max(chicks[chicks['parent']==4,]$datestamp, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @Keeley, if it solves your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.